# Getting real-time data from firestore using React Context Hook API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to have real-time connection with firebase firestore database and update UI after I add or remove some data from collection. I already tried using onSnapshot function but the thing is, when I go to a diffrent route and load other component, all data that was previously in database get change.type === "added" again even if they existed before. So when I get this data its repeating in the context and I'm getting doubled data on the screen, also map function throws an error bcs of redundant key attribute value. What should I do to avoid this? I'm using context hook API + reducers and action creators, no redux!

```
export const getProjects = (dispatch) => {
firestore.collection('projects').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        if(change.type === "added"){
             dispatch({type:'SET_PROJECTS', data: {
                title: change.doc.data().title,
                content: change.doc.data().content,
                id: change.doc.id
            }})
        }
    })
})
```

}

```
export const projectReducer = (state, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERR':
        console.log('Create project error', action.err.message);
        return state
    case 'SET_PROJECTS':
        return [...state,{
            title: action.data.title,
            content: action.data.content,
            id: action.data.id
        }]
    default: 
        return state
}
```

}

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getProjects(dispatch);
}, [dispatch])
```

That's the code that connects with firestore and get data and also reducer that set's it into the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onSnapshot *always* calls the dataCallback at *least* once, and then *again* on any changes.  Your reducer is simply appending the results to the existing state, so that likely explains why you see it *twice* - you need to be a tad more subtle to *replace* existing entries.

I usually work with Redux (rather than Context), but I have a number of instances where my Listeners update Redux state, and the existing Redux connectors update React.  And yes,my reducers take care of duplicates.

Comment: Yeah I know how onSnapshot works but when I change the route in my react app all the data that's coming from firestore has added status once again, that's why I'm getting back duplicated data, can u try to show me how to take care of duplicates  if possible? I have no idea how to do it, bcs I cant send all the data to reducer, it must be one record every single time so I must use "...state" to get previous state or I would lose every data every single time, help me out if u can, and also thank you for response.

Comment: Literally dozens of techniques to maintain a unique list, so rather a broad question. "A" technique is to update your state [...state, [action.data.id]: {title: action.data.title, content: action.data.content}] (or as an object rather than an array, {...state, [action.data.id]: {title: action.data.title, content: action.data.content}}; they're functionally pretty equivalent)  -  i.e. 'action.data.id' becomes the index